# Function reference in a Java annotation parameter

Tags: java, annotations

I have a jersey resource method annotated with custom annotation `@InBound(responseLog = true, requestLog = true)`.  The annotation basically logs request and response for each incoming request into a db table, so that these can be looked later for debugging.

Definition of  the annotation is as below:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface InBound {

    boolean requestLog() default false;

    boolean responseLog() default false;
}
```

I want to accept one more argument in annotation which will be basically an object of Type `java.util.function.Function` to do an awesome task(find a unique key from the request).

Can annotations accept Function in parameters? If yes, Can you please help with an example?